# How can I repeat each text field in a column the number of times given in another column?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, r

I have a file, say 'test.txt' with:

```
5 80  
3 70  
4 60
```

Now I want to create an R plot that looks like stairs/steps: y-value 80 for 5 data points, then y-value 70 for 3 data points and then y-value 60 for 4 data points, something like this:

[image: stairs plot example]

How could I transform the `test.txt` to `transformed.txt`:

```
80  
80  
80  
80  
80  
70  
70  
70  
60  
60  
60  
60
```

on the shell, or, alternatively directly print the plot in R from `test.txt`.

Comment: Reviewers: This isn't off-topic. It's about how to process text from the command line so it's compatible with R -- or, alternatively, how to *invoke* R -- and not how to program in R. (See [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/870599), for example.) I've edited the title to clarify this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) is good for this:

```bash
awk '{while ($1-- > 0) print $2}' test.txt
```

This interprets each line of `test.txt` as a record of fields separated by spaces. It counts down (`--`) from the value of the first field (`$1`) until that value is zero, printing the value of the second field (`$2`) on its own line each time.

One of the advantages of this method is that it automatically tolerates extra whitespace before, in between, or after the numbers.

Specifically:

- [`$1` and `$2` are the first and second fields.](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Fields.html#Fields)
- [The `while`-loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/While-Statement.html#While-Statement) evaluates the expression `$1-- > 0`. If it's true, then `print $2` runs, then [starts over again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow#Loops).
- The subexpression `$1--` diminishes the value of the first field by one. (This happens in memory; the actual file `text.txt` is never modified.) But it *returns* the value `$1` had just before it was decreased. See [Gawk: Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/), section [6.2.4 Increment and Decrement Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Increment-Ops.html), for a more thorough explanation.

If you prefer, you can instead use a [`for`-loop](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/For-Statement.html#For-Statement):

```
awk '{for (; $1 > 0; --$1) print $2}' test.txt
```

Or with a dedicated loop counter [variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Variables.html#Variables):

```
awk '{for (i = $1; i > 0; --i) print $2}' test.txt
```

Or if you find it more intuitive to count up instead of down, you can do that:

```
awk '{for (i = 0; i < $1; ++i) print $2}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Using Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d+) (\d+\n)/$2 x $1/e' foo
```

Here:

- `-pe` runs the expression on every line, automatically printing it afterwards
- `(\d+)` matches a string of digits, and `(\d+\n)` matches a string of digits with a newline
- Then `$2 x $1` replicates the second matched group as many times as the value of the first matched group. `/e` tells Perl that the replacement is also to be evaluated as a Perl expression